# Django test script to pre-populate DB

Tags: django, testing

I'm trying to pre-populate the database with some test data for my Django project. Is there some easy way to do this with a script that's "outside" of Django?

Let's say I want to do this very simple task, creating 5 test users using the following code,

```
N = 10
i = 0
while i < N:
    c = 'user' + str(i) + '@gmail.com'
    u = lancer.models.CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=c, password="12345")
    i = i + 1
```

The questions are,

1. WHERE do I put this test script file?
2. WHAT IMPORTS / COMMANDS do I need to put at the beginning of the file so it has access to all the Django environment & resources as if I were writing this inside the app?

I'm thinking you'd have to import and set up the settings file, and import the app's models, etc... but all my attempts have failed one way or another, so would appreciate some help =)

Thanks!

**Providing another answer**

The respondes below are excellent answers. I fiddled around and found an alternative way. I added the following to the top of the test data script,

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from project_lancer import settings
setup_environ(settings)
import lancer.models
```

Now my code above works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use fixtures for these purposes:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

If you still want to use this initial code then read:

If you use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) you can create migration and put this code there:

```
python manage.py schemamigration --empty my_data_migration

class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    no_dry_run = False

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # more pythonic, you can also use bulk_insert here 
        for i in xrange(10):
            email = "user{}@gmail.com".format(i)
            u = orm.CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=email, password='12345)
```

You can put it to setUp method of your TestCase:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # more pythonic, you can also use bulk_insert here 
        for i in xrange(10):
            email = "user{}@gmail.com".format(i)
            u = lancer.models.CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=email,
                                                             password='12345')
    def test_foo(self):
        pass
```

Also you can define your BaseTestCase in which you override setUp method then you create your TestCase classes that inherit from BaseTestCase:

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        'your initial logic here'


class MyFirstTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    pase

class MySecondTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    pase
```

But I think that fixtures is the best way:

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['users_for_test.json']

class MyFirstTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    pase

class MySecondTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    fixtures = ['special_users_for_only_this_test_case.json']
```

Updated:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
make_password('12312312')
'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$9KQ15rVsxZ0t$xMEKUicxtRjfxHobZ7I9Lh56B6Pkw7K8cO0ow2qCKdc='
```

Comment: Actually I ran into another problem with fixtures: how would I define a password field? These passwords are being stored as a complex long string that I don't know how they've generated.

Comment: You can just insert few users through django-admin then run python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent 4 > users.json

Comment: I updated my post to show the way how to generate passwords if you cannot use the previous way (django-admin).

Comment: Awesome! That's great to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [something like this](http://aerosol.github.io/django-dilla/) [or this](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture) to auto-populate your models for testing purposes.

Comment: I also like https://github.com/joke2k/faker, looks promising even though it's not targeting Django specifically.